# How to do a determinant in ArrayFire?

Tags: arrayfire

How can i made a simple determinant in a af::array?

Tryed to use in af::array x:
af::det(x)
det(x)
x.det()

and dont works.

Someone can help me?

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘det(af::array&)’
  if(det(x) == 0){

candidate: template<class T> T af::det(const af::array&)
     template<typename T> T det(const array &in);
                        ^
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://arrayfire.org/docs/group__lapack__ops__func__det.htm#ga17c069073fc6ccfe4d4b32829ae8342c), the function is templated. You should try something like this instead:

```cpp
std::cout << af::det<float>(x);
```